# Double value not considering 00 after decimal point iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, double, nsnumber

In my application user enters price in text field. So I take the price from textfield like below

```
NSNumber *price = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:[[self stringAfterRemovingCurrencySymbol:self.priceTextField.text] doubleValue]];
```

When I print the value like below

```
DLog(@"Price Value 1: %f",[[self stringAfterRemovingCurrencySymbol:self.buyTextField.text] doubleValue]);

DLog(@"Price Value 2: %@",price);
```

Here is output (Lets say user enters 150.00)

```
Price Value 1: 150.000000
Price Value 2: 150
```

What I want is

```
Price Value 1: 150.000000
Price Value 2: 150.00
```

If user enters 150.85 , I am getting 150.85 as it is. But when user enters .00 , I am not getting .00

What should I do so that I will get the .00 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the NSNumber's value as a double and use standard printf formatting to specify precision:

```
DLog(@"Price Value 2: %.2f", [price doubleValue]);
```

Comment: Here I am passing Price as NSNumber in parameter dictionary to server. So it doesn't take .00